# The basis for $V=R[x]/(x^3-x)$ quotient space

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces

I need to find the dimension of the basis for $V=R[x]/(x^3-x)$ - I don't need to find the basis itself just its dimension but it would be nice to find it as well.I think that $V$ is the set of all polynomials in the form of $ v(x) + q(x)(x^3-x) $ for some $ q(x) \in R[x] $ where $v(x)$ is the remainder of the division of a polynomial in  $R[x] $ with $(x^3-x)$.
But here i'm stuck. My initiation is that  $ q(x)(x^3-x) $ is the zero vector for $V$ and I need to find the basis for the vectors not in $ q(x)(x^3-x) $ but I'm not sure if $ q(x)(x^3-x) $ includes all polynomials of order 3 or above and if yes how to prove it.

Thanks!

Comment: Informally, you can think of this space as being all polynomials up to degree $2$, and whenever you have anything above degree $3$ you use the relation $x^3 = x$ to repeatedly convert any higher order terms to something lower. So a basis could be $\{1, x, x^2\}$

Comment: As for formally, what does the division algorithm tell you for any polynomial with degree $3$ or greater when you divide by $x^3-x$?

Comment: You probably meant the basis is $ \{1+q(x)(x^3-x), x+q(x)(x^3-x),x^2 +q(x)(x^3-x) \} $ because each vector in this space is a linear space of vectors.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Unfortunately by abuse of notation, people (me included right here) often write $1$ to mean the coset of $1$ instead of using some notation like $[1]$.

Comment: The set of all polynomials of the form $v(x) + q(x)(x^3-x)$ for some $q(x) \in R[x]$ is the so-called *coset* of $v(x)$, which we will denote it by, say, $\overline{v(x)}$. In other words, $\overline{v(x)} = \{v(x) + q(x)(x^3-x) : q(x) \in R[x]\}$. Thus, $R[x]/(x^3-x) = \{\overline{v(x)} : v(x) \in R[x]\}$, and a basis for it is $\{\overline{1}, \overline{x}, \overline{x^2}\}$.